# Could not find variants for component

Tags: sxa, site-configuration

I have created custom variant render called “Success Story”, I create custom variant to display the “description”  only, however the view display “ Description field” with no value, when I look at logs I found `WARN  Could not find variants for component {6D6DD358-64AF-4539-95FA-769A8CDDEB05} from page {4C5BE406-5A93-47BE-83A9-530B19F55C83}`

I follow below steps:
1 - Inherit form VariantsController

```
public class SuccessStoryController : VariantsController
{
    protected ISuccessStoryRepository SuccessStoryRespository
    { get; set; }
    protected ISuccessStoryListRepository SuccessStoryListRespository
    { get; set; }


    protected IVariantsRepository VariantsRespository
    { get; set; }

    public SuccessStoryController()
    {
        SuccessStoryRespository = ServiceLocator.Current.Resolve<ISuccessStoryRepository>();
        SuccessStoryListRespository = ServiceLocator.Current.Resolve<ISuccessStoryListRepository>();
        VariantsRespository = ServiceLocator.Current.Resolve<IVariantsRepository>();
    }

    protected override object GetModel()
    {
        return SuccessStoryListRespository.GetModel();
    }
}


 public class SuccessStoryModel : VariantsRenderingModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
}public class SuccessStoryListModel : VariantListsRenderingModel 
{

    public List<SuccessStoryModel> SuccessStoryItems { get; set; }
}
```

4 - The view as below

```
if (!(Model.Rendering.DataSourceItem == null && !Html.Sxa().IsEdit))
{
    <div @Html.Sxa().Component("SuccessStory-list", Model.Attributes)>
        <div class="component-content">

            @Html.Sxa().RenderHeading(Model.HeadingTag, Model.DataSourceItem, "Title", Model.GetRenderingWebEditingParams())

            @if (Html.Sxa().IsEdit && Model.Rendering.DataSourceItem == null)
            {
                @Model.MessageIsEmpty
            }

            @if (Model.Rendering.DataSourceItem != null && !Model.SuccessStoryItems.Any())
            {
                using (Html.Sxa().BeginEditFrame(Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.DataSource, "Empty", Model.IsControlEditable))
                {
                    @Model.MessageIsEmpty
                }
            }

            @if (Model.Rendering.DataSourceItem != null)
            {
                <ul>


                    @foreach (var item in Model.SuccessStoryItems)
                    {
                        <div data-itemid="ccc">

                         @foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
                         {

                            @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, true)

                         }


                        </div>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My parameter template inhert from :
[image]

My render as below and I add it to available render

[image]

my repo

```
    public class SuccessStoryListRepository : ListRepository, ISuccessStoryListRepository, IModelRepository, IAbstractRepository<IRenderingModelBase>
{
    public override IRenderingModelBase GetModel()
    {
        SuccessStoryListModel model = new SuccessStoryListModel();
        this.FillBaseProperties(model);
        //BindSuccessStory();
        model.SuccessStoryItems = BindSuccessStory(); //this.GetItems().Select<Item, SuccessStoryModel>((Func<Item, SuccessStoryModel>)(item => new SuccessStoryModel()));
        return (IRenderingModelBase)model;
    }

    private List<SuccessStoryModel> BindSuccessStory()
    {
       var  items=this.GetItems().ToList();

        List<SuccessStoryModel> list = new List<SuccessStoryModel>();


        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //item.Fields["Description"].Value;

            list.Add(new SuccessStoryModel
            {
                Description = item.Fields["Description"].Value,
                Title= item.Fields["Title"].Value

            });
        }
        return list;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - it looks like you are rendering this out wrong. Take a look at your loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SuccessStoryItems)
{
    <div data-itemid="ccc">
     @foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
     {
        @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, true)
     }
    </div>
}
```

So you are looping through `Model.SuccessStoryItems` - but then in your look, you are passing in `Model.Item` - that will be the same item for every entry in the loop. It looks like you should be passing in the `item` variable you are declaring in your loop.

**But** when you have created your `SuccessStoryModel`, you have added fields for `Description` and `Title`. The `@Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant()` method, needs a Sitecore Item, so you will need to modify the code to pass this in.

First, change your `SuccessStoryListModel` like to have a list of `Item` objects like this:

```
public class SuccessStoryListModel : VariantListsRenderingModel 
{
    public List<Item> SuccessStoryItems { get; set; }
}
```

Now modify your `BindSuccessStory` method to populate that list like this:

```
private List<Item> BindSuccessStory()
{
    var  items = this.GetItems().ToList();

    var list = new List<Item>();
    list.AddRange(items);
    return list;
}
```

Finally, modify your view to use that item like this:

```
@foreach (var successStoryItem in Model.SuccessStoryItems)
{
    <div data-itemid="ccc">
     @foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
     {
        @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, successStoryItem, true)
     }
    </div>
}
```

Now you are passing in the item that has the field you want to be rendered correctly and it should get rendered as the variant field.

Answer (score 0):

Messages like "*FIELD_NAME field*" (e.g. "*Description field*" like in your case) means that the field specified in the variant item doesn't exist on the context item passed to the variant renderer. As far as I can see you are rendering variants like that:

```
@Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, true)
```

so ensure that `Model.Item` is exactly the item you want to use and if it contains "Description" field (or any other field which you'll specify in the variant items).

Comment: my looks like below , do i miss anything ?

Comment: thanks for your help, i add my repo class can you help me on what is wrong there ?